# java sql return id from insert query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have the next SQL template:

```
INSERT_QUERY   = "INSERT INTO "article" (article_table, article_id) VALUES ({1}, {2}) RETURNING article_id";
```

I can not change this template. The task is to return id from sql base. What I have done:

```
PreparedStatement insert_query = db.prepareStatement(String.format(INSERT_QUERY, table, id));
insert_query.executeUpdate();
ResultSet result_id = insert_query.getGeneratedKeys();
if(result_id.next()){
   id = result_id.getInt(1);
}
System.out.println(this.id);
```

But this code do insert values but not return nothing((

> Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A
>   result was returned when none was expected.

If I change to:

```
db.prepareStatement(String.format(INSERT_QUERY, table, id), PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

The sql query becomes:

```
INSERT INTO "article" (article_table, article_id) 
VALUES ({1}, {2}) RETURNING article_id RETURNING *
```

which is invalid. 
So my question is there any way I can use existing template to return id or eventually I need to change it?

Comment: If you use `getGeneratedKeys()` you don't need the `returning` clause. If you use the `returning` clause you need to use `execute()` and then `insert_query.getResultSet()` check the JavaDocs for the `execute()` method for details

Comment: Yes, working for me)